# Apache Phoenix Bulk Data Loading - Can't use table name by small letter

Tags: apache-phoenix, bulk-load, bulkloader

i have existing Phoenix table abc
i wanna Bulk Data Loading via MapReduce
And then used the following command to load the csv file

hadoop jar /root/Phoenix/apache-phoenix-4.8.0-HBase-0.98-bin/phoenix-4.8.0-HBase-0.98-client.jar org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool --t abc --input /example.csv

but, it does not seem to find the table abc

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Table ABC not found

i try change command table name --t 'abc' and --t "abc"
but it doesn't work
how can i use table name small letter ??

And also, i found same case

[http://apache-phoenix-user-list.1124778.n5.nabble.com/Load-into-Phoenix-table-via-CsvBulkLoadTool-cannot-find-table-and-fails-td2792.html](http://i%20have%20existing%20Phoenix%20table%20abc%20i%20wanna%20Bulk%20Data%20Loading%20via%20MapReduce%20And%20then%20used%20the%20following%20command%20to%20load%20the%20csv%20file%20hadoop%20jar%20/root/Phoenix/apache-phoenix-4.8.0-HBase-0.98-bin/phoenix-4.8.0-HBase-0.98-client.jar%20org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool%20--t%20abc%20--input%20/example.csv%20but,%20it%20does%20not%20seem%20to%20find%20the%20table%20abc%20Exception%20in%20thread%20%22main%22%20java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:%20Table%20ABC%20not%20found%20i%20try%20change%20command%20table%20name%20--t%20'abc'%20and%20--t%20%22abc%22%20but%20it%20doesn't%20work%20how%20can%20i%20use%20table%20name%20small%20letter%20??%20And%20also,%20i%20found%20same%20case%20http://apache-phoenix-user-list.1124778.n5.nabble.com/Load-into-Phoenix-table-via-CsvBulkLoadTool-cannot-find-table-and-fails-td2792.html)

thanks

Comment: I have done similar thing and able to reproduce the issue you are saying. But I think in the job parameter, you can do use the string toUpperCase method for the same. I believe It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, after a lot of debugging I realized that phoenix converts you input "abc" into all caps "ABC" and tries to look for a table with this name. And Phoenix is case sensitive as mentioned [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/bulk_dataload.html).

Try to create your table in phoenix shell with all caps and then run the same command, it should work just fine.

Sample table creation and bulk upload via mapreduce:

```
CREATE TABLE "CODEFREQUENCY" (pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,"week"."weekNum" VARCHAR,"week"."addition" VARCHAR,"week"."deletion" VARCHAR);
```

---

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hbase mapredcp):~/Installs/Hbase/conf/:~/Installs/apache-phoenix-4.10.0-HBase-1.2-bin/ ./hadoop jar ~/Installs/apache-phoenix-4.10.0-HBase-1.2-bin/phoenix-4.10.0-HBase-1.2-client.jar org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool -Dfs.permissions.umask-mode=000 -d $'\t' -t CODEFREQUENCY --input /hbase/Code_Frequency.csv
```